# Forming $r$ letter words out of a $n$ letter word with some letters being repeated

Tags: combinatorics

I have this counting problem: I have to form 3 letter words with or without meaning from the letters of the word **combination**. I can see that there are 2 n's,2 i's and 2 o's causing over counted answer. The answer given is $63+8P3$. I don't know how to arrive at this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it this way: for a three-letter word constructed from a set with three pairs of repeated letters, there are only two possible cases: $1$) we have two repeated letters and one other letter (in the form $AAB$) *or* $2$) we have three different letters. Also notice that the word "combination" has $5$ letters that are non-duplicates.

To construct a word in the first case, we choose the repeated letter (which can be done in $3$ ways, since there are three repeat letters), the other letter (which can be done $5 + 2 = 7$ ways), and finally we arrange them. Since there are three arrangements per letter set, this count is $3 \times 7 \times 3 = 63.$

To construct a word in the second case, we choose three letters from a collection of $8$ (we simply remove duplicated letters), which can be done in $\dbinom{8}{3}$ ways. Then we arrange the letter set, which can be done in $3!$ ways. The total count is $\dbinom{8}{3} \times 3!,$ which is the same as $_{8}P_{3}.$

Our final answer is the sum of these two distinct cases, which is $\boxed{63 + _{8}P_{3}}.$

Answer (score 0):

It seems the given answer has counted the number of each of two different kinds of words, and them together:

1. A word containing two of some letter
2. A word containing three different letters.

There are $63$ words of the first kind (note that there are two o's as well), and $_8P_3$ words of the second kind.